# All Applications Disappear in the Dash

Tags: unity-dash, shortcuts, search

After installing the latest update, all my applications disappear in the dash?

It always show me : `Sorry, there is noting that matches yours search.`

[image]

Why? How to fix it?

**Thank you for your help.**

Comment: close it. And just simply press super+A.

Comment: super = Windows Logo? If yes, sorry...it does not work. =[

Comment: yep. Windows Key aka super key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run
`rm ~/.cache/software-center -R`

and then : open the terminal hit Alt-F2
 run the following command `unity --reset`

Comment: [1] 14914
casper@casper-UX32VD:~$ ERROR: the reset option is now deprecated

Comment: I've edited the answer.. sorry didn't notice that.

Comment: After runing the command, my laptop cannot detect any WiFi signals...so sad and come back windows (´･_･`)

Comment: Restart your Ubuntu and see again.

Comment: Have tried, not work(´･_･`)

Comment: Are you sure your applications are still installed ?, try running gedit