# Newly installed application is not found until log-out

Tags: launcher, unity-dash, 16.04

I'm running a Ubuntu 16.04 machine and I noticed that whenever I install a new package (from command-line, I didn't try the Software center) I cannot find it, if I look for it by  hitting <kbd>Super</kbd>. The package is installed fine, because I can call it by its name in the Terminal and there's the respective `.desktop` file in `/usr/share/applications`. However if I log out and log in again, I can find the application via <kbd>Super</kbd>.

Is this normal behavior?

Answer (score -1):

I already had this issue since 15.10 and its the same in 16.04 now.

Its very similar to a problem stated [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/501880/applications-dont-appear-in-the-dash-14-04) where it was  zeitgeist related. Reinstantiating the zeitgeist db seemed to help. I did not try it though.