# Some programs don't appear in the Applications menu

Tags: 16.04, chromium, mate, appmenu

Some applications don't appear in Applications menu MATE Desktop Environment. For instance, I would expect Chromium to show up under *Internet*... but it doesn't.

[image: MATE Applications menu]

I've checked all categories and tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/506072/530811) which gave me the following outputs:

```
$ desktop-file-validate .local/share/applications/*.desktop
.local/share/applications/chromium-browser.desktop: warning: key "Encoding" in group "Desktop Entry" is deprecated
.local/share/applications/_opt_sublime_text_sublime_text.desktop: warning: key "Encoding" in group "Desktop Entry" is deprecated
.local/share/applications/sublime_text.desktop: warning: key "Encoding" in group "Desktop Entry" is deprecated
.local/share/applications/sublime_text.desktop: error: (will be fatal in the future): value "sublime_text.png" for key "Icon" in group "Desktop Entry" is an icon name with an extension, but there should be no extension as described in the Icon Theme Specification if the value is not an absolute path
```

and

```
$ desktop-file-validate .gnome/apps/*.desktop
(no output)
```

and

```
$ desktop-file-validate /usr/share/applications/*.desktop
```

[Outputs this](https://paste.ubuntu.com/18227436/)

I can't also find Sublime Text under the category *Programming*, but LibreOffice Math is listed under *Education*.

How do I fix this and make Sublime Text, Chromium and other applications show up in the right category? I would prefer an automated solution for all applications, but a solution to specifically fix Sublime Text and Chromium would okay if no such automated solution exists.

### Update

I've installed `alacarte`, and run it with `gsku alacarte` (I found that running `alacarte` with normal priviliges doesn't even show all applications in Main Menu). I see that Chromium and Sublime Text are checked, and even are in the right categories, but they still don't show up in the Applications menu.

Comment: Weird! on my system `alacarte` doesn't exist... the menu editor I get with right click on applications can also be accessed via Control Centre > Look & Feel > Main Menu. Do you have anything there?

Comment: @Zanna yup, I see it! But it still won't work. I can delete items but not add new ones.

Comment: I have also discovered that changing the menu options doesn't change .desktop files in /usr/share/applications (most don't have entries in ~/.local)... still investigating!

Comment: Looking at the errors from desktop-file-validate in ~/.local... seems those `.desktop` files have fatal errors and need to be edited. If you post the contents of the files, we can figure out how to fix them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click the menu button and you can edit the menus to choose which installed applications appear. I had a similar problem & was surprised by the simplicity of the solution!

If you don't see the option, you first need to

```
sudo apt-get install alacarte
```

[image]

If *Edit Menu* isn't visible, do <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type `alacarte`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't see the 'Edit' option

Comment: I found I have to install `alacarte` (source: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2143361). I'll now log out and log in and see what happens.

Comment: I've logged out and logged in, but I still can't see the option. I'm rebooting now.

Comment: See updated question

Comment: @grooveplex well that's very nice of you but I don't think your question was unanswerable (some tweaking of the `.desktop` files would have fixed it I believe... Still, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For alacarte to work, I had to use a **128x128 jpg**. (Open the icon in kolourpaint, resize it (Menu-Image-Resize) to 128x128 and save as jpg.)